# Why potentially dangerous request error even ValidateRequest = false

Tags: .net-4.0, asp.net-4.0

Here is my Default.aspx

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true"  CodeFile="Default.aspx.cs" Inherits="_Default" ValidateRequest="false" %>
<html>
    <head runat="server">
        <title>xss demonstration</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <form id="form1" runat="server">
        <div>
            We are looking for your feedback. 
            <asp:TextBox ID="txtFeedback" runat="server" TextMode="MultiLine" />
            <br />
            <asp:Button ID="submit" runat="server" Text="Submit" onclick="submit_Click" />
            <br />
            Comment: 
            <br />
            <asp:Literal ID="ltlFeedback" runat="server" />
        </div>
        </form>
    </body>
</html>
```

And below is Default.aspx.cs

```
public partial class _Default : System.Web.UI.Page 
{
    protected void submit_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        this.ltlFeedback.Text = this.txtFeedback.Text;
    }
}
```

When I run the application and enter following in the text box.

```
<script>alert('Hello')</script>
```

I get following error.

> A potentially dangerous Request.Form value was detected from the
>   client (txtFeedback="alert('Hello...").

My question is why I get this error even though ValidateRequest is set to false in the page?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

In .net framework 4.0 you have to set  `<httpRuntime requestValidationMode="2.0"/>` markup in web.config.

```
<system.web>
     <compilation debug="false" targetFramework="4.0" />
     <httpRuntime requestValidationMode="2.0"/>
</system.web>
```

Have a look at reference article - [ASP.NET 4 Breaking Changes #1: requestValidationMode cause ValidateRequest=False to fail](http://jefferytay.wordpress.com/2010/04/15/asp-net-4-breaking-changes-1-requestvalidationmode-cause-validaterequestfalse-to-fail/).

Answer (score 0):

you just need to Add following code in your web config

```
   <system.web>
         <compilation debug="false" targetFramework="4.0" />
         <httpRuntime requestValidationMode="2.0"/>
 </system.web>
```

but take care by doing this you can be victim of cross site scripting attack

Answer (score 0):

### Disable ValidateRequest on any pages retrieved via Server.Execute

I recently ran into a rather esoteric version of this error. In order to include shared content across pages in different sites, I call `Server.Execute` on another ASPX page. By default, `Server.Execute` will forward the POST data along to the child request, so this page *also* needs `ValidateRequest="false"`.

As long as `<httpRuntime requestValidationMode="2.0"/>` in `web.config` is set, the exception's stack trace will indicate which page class raised the error.